# Order a list of XElement by attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm familiar with the OrderBy linq extension method but cannot seem to get my query returning any results - after playing for quite a while with the Linq and XElement methods to find the attribute of a child element!

I've built a list of Xelements which contain the following eg data:

```
+       [0] {<Inserted>
<rowData ID="A7-6A-1B-0A-19-44-BF-0A-79-63-7D-AA-12-62-54-98" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <c r="A2">
    <v>61108</v>
    </c>
    <c r="B2" t="s">
    <v>7</v>
    </c>
    <c r="C2">
    <v>1000111</v>
    </c>
    <c r="D2" t="s">
    <v>8</v>
    </c>
    <c r="E2">
    <v>200</v>
    </c>
    <c r="F2" t="s">
    <v>9</v>
    </c>
    <c r="G2" t="s">
    <v>10</v>
    </c>
</rowData>
</Inserted>}    System.Xml.Linq.XElement
+       [1] {<Inserted>
<rowData ID="6F-78-AB-C2-E9-8E-94-E7-18-96-97-DA-84-9C-E3-4C" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <c r="A7">
    <v>611025</v>
    </c>
    <c r="B7" t="s">
    <v>11</v>
    </c>
    <c r="C7">
    <v>61004</v>
    </c>
    <c r="D7" t="s">
    <v>12</v>
    </c>
    <c r="E7">
    <v>40</v>
    </c>
    <c r="F7" t="s">
    <v>10</v>
    </c>
    <c r="G7" t="s">
    <v>10</v>
    </c>
</rowData>
</Inserted>}    System.Xml.Linq.XElement
+       [2] {<Deleted>
<rowData ID="CA-B9-3B-71-B9-FE-35-11-FF-AA-12-A7-24-96-09-9A" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <c r="A2">
    <v>61008</v>
    </c>
    <c r="B2" t="s">
    <v>7</v>
    </c>
    <c r="C2">
    <v>1000111</v>
    </c>
    <c r="D2" t="s">
    <v>8</v>
    </c>
    <c r="E2">
    <v>200</v>
    </c>
    <c r="F2" t="s">
    <v>9</v>
    </c>
    <c r="G2" t="s">
    <v>10</v>
    </c>
</rowData>
</Deleted>} System.Xml.Linq.XElement
```

As you can see the root tag can be < Inserted > or < Deleted >.
My query is simple (in spite of my asking!): I need to order by the r attribute of the c element, such that either the first or third element of the list should be ordered first (with value < c r="A2" >, then ordered by the second element in the list (< c r="A7" >)

EDIT: I think I'm struggling with my fluent queries due to the fact that the rowData element has a different namespace to the root (just a guess as I have no experience working with xml). I'll try remove the ns from that element as it's not important and keep trying but any help is welcome

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: testing me? sure I'll edit post with an eg: List<XElement> orderedList = finalList.OrderBy(x => x.Element(sourceDoc.Name.NamespaceName + "c").FirstAttribute.Value).ToList();

Comment: From an ordering perspective, do you only care about the first `<c>` element of each `<rowData>` section? Or do you want this to trickle down and use subsequent elements as well?

Comment: @RionWilliams Hi Rion, only the first will suffice :)

Answer (score 0):

As my earlier EDIT suggested, this was in fact due to different namespaces within the XML, causing me massive heartache in finding elements etc.

I duly stripped them all via a recursive method found on SO

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a collection of `XElement` objects that each refer to the nodes defined in your example, you should be able to do a bit of trickery by ordering based on the first descendant of each node :

```
// This pulls the first <c> descendant node and reads it value
var ordered = unordered.OrderBy(n => (n.DescendantNodes().ElementAt(1) as XElement)?.FirstAttribute?.Value);
```

This could likely be dramatically improved via proper querying i.e. targeting `<c>` elements and simply using the first one, but this should work and can be [seen in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BlYjtE).